# Flask validate_on_submit always False

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I know that there are similar problems which have been answered. The `csrf_enabled` is not an issue now if the `Form` inheriting `FlaskForm`,  and the template has the `form.hidden_tag()`.

I have the following flask app.

```
## Filenname: app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"



class DataForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    gender = SelectField("Gender", validators=None, choices=[(1, 'M'), (2, "F")])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit", validators=None)



@app.route('/index', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = DataForm(request.form)
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.validate())
        print(form.name)
        flash("THIS IS FLASH")
        title="hello"
        return redirect(url_for('output'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)



@app.route('/output', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def output():
    title = "hello"
    form = DataForm()
    print(form.validate())
    return render_template('output.html', title=title)


app.run(debug=False)
```

The following is index.html template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {{ messages }}
        {% endwith %}



        <form action="" method="GET">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.name.label }}
            {{ form.name() }}
            {% for error in form.name.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}

            <hr>

            {{ form.gender.label }}
            {{ form.gender() }}

            {{ form.submit() }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After clicking the `submit` button the execution never goes in the `if form.validate_on_submit()` block in the `index` function.

I also removed all the validators, the code inside `validate_on_submit` block is still unreachable. Printing `form.validate_on_submit()` is always false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask WTForms always give false on validate\_on\_submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716920/flask-wtforms-always-give-false-on-validate-on-submit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So there are multiple problems.

1. Change your choices to strings:

   ```
   choices=[('1', 'M'), ('2', "F")]
   ```
2. Change your form method to POST, because `validate_on_submit()` requires it:

   ```
   <form action="" method="POST">
   ```
3. Additionally, to debug other possible errors (like CSRF), add this to your template:

   ```
   {% if form.errors %}
   {{ form.errors }}
   {% endif %}
   ```

That fixed your code for me.

Comment: I had tried with `"POST"` too (`"POST"` is the right method). The main problem were the choices, instead of using the integer 1 one should use the string '1' as you have pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Just print `csrf_token` with jinja and it will return `True`.

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
   {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. just make form without

2.form = FlaskForm(meta={'csrf': False})