# Why is my function not entering the IF statement and rendering flash message in python

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm making an app that once you have registered with a valid email it should flash a message and return you to the login page. Currently it is not flashing the message and is returning to the register page. I've placed a print statement and it is not entering my if-statement. I've watched tutorials and looked through documentation and stack overflow content. I cant figure out where I'm wrong.

app.py

```
    @app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        form = RegistrationForm()
        print('test')
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

layout.html

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">{{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

I'm hoping that it is something simple and that I am just overlooking it.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455689/flask-validate-on-submit-always-false

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722968/flask-wtf-validate-on-submit-is-never-executed

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the python code.